# How to best incorporate Workout, Yoga, Shower and Eating together into a routine?

Tags: exercise, diet, health, yoga, routine

I'm trying to fit **workouts, yoga, showering, and eating** into a daily routine, preferably together. There are lots of approaches to the **order** and **time gap** of doing these which is really confusing for me when coming up with a routine.

What I've decided myself according to some research is to do them in this order after waking up:

1. Workout (Strength / Aerobic)
2. Yoga
3. Spend about 30 mins doing other
   activities (cause you shouldn't do the next two immediately after
   the above)
4. Shower
5. Eat

I wanted to see how healthy my approach is and if anything needs changing.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you shouldn't shower directly after a workout. Is that a documented "don't"?

Comment: @Alec Right? There are no "other activities" I want to do after workouts, cuz I'm gross.

Comment: @Alec It's not about the workout, it more has to do with yoga. Showering right before and after yoga is not a good practice and so working out, showering, and then waiting some time to do yoga just doesn't seem convenient to me as I'm interested in the recovering and stretching effects that yoga brings after a workout session.

Comment: "Showering right before and after yoga is not a good practice": But why?

Comment: You can eat immediately after you do your workout, or yoga. Yoga essentially is just stretching or working on mobility/core/balance. You might do some work for your core or balance muscles such as glute medius/minimus so yoga you can do at any time. For your benefit, doing a workout, then immediately a yoga session would help stretch your muscles from your workout, then eating after to restore glycogen/protein etc and if you're building muscle/strength you should def eat right after your workout, or yoga(if yoga is 30 min or less). Not sure why showering is on this list,